# Docker and Elasticsearch - Date ingestion not working

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

### Docker Compose YML

```
...
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
      - ./data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
...
```

I have a `.json` file in my `data` dir. I run `docker-compose up` and nothing gets persisted within ES.

What exactly needs to be done here? I'm running Docker on Mac. I've tried various `.json` files, to no avail.

Comment: Bind mounting a `data` folder doesn't cause ES to automatically ingest the data. It's purpose is to have the ES data folder available outside of the container on your Mac. AFAIK you would still need to ingest the data (via a `curl PUT` or similar in the container)

Comment: What's the best way to do that during docker build?